# How to access MongoDB _id of a Document when wanting to use findById for instance?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I know that when we create a new document from a model, Mongo automatically generates an

`ObjectId`for it under key `"_id"`.

If this `_id: ObjectId` is not defined in the model, it will still be generated. In this case, if I want to use the query method findById, which will require the `ObjectId _id` of the document, how do I access it?

Typescript will often not recognize it.

Is the only way for this to define manually in the model this specific `ObjectId`?

Example of simple Document for illustration (I'm using Nest), without _id manually defined:

```
@ObjectType("Package")
@InputType("PackageInput")
@Schema()
export class Package {
    @Field(() => String)
    @Prop({ type: String })
    status: PackageStatusesEnums;

    @Field(() => String)
    @Prop()
    statusReason: string;

    @Prop({ type: Object })
    dimensions: PackageDimensions;

    @Field(() => String)
    @Prop()
    notes: string;
```

Then in code calling

```
const pckgRes = await this.findById(pckg._id)
```

Will show a TS error :

> Property '_id' does not exist on type 'Package'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 const pckgRes = await this.findById({_id: pckg._id})
```